# android listitem from server and stores data to database

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to do mail program. i've done this using jsonArray, Http protocals and some other functions. But, now i want to implement the program likely unread mails and starred mails. If i'm pressing anyof new mail it'll assign likely 1 to database. Otherwise, keep it 0. And, also if i want to set any mails in important (starred) this will keep 1 to database. Otherwise, keep 0. Now, i want to create a database related to these concepts? Anyone know about this concept Please help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQLite,

Below tutorial will help you to get started,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview_sqlite

Good luck!

Edited :

Create a database with a table "Whatever name"

Than have content such as

```
|SeqNo|MailFrom|MailTo|Subject|Body|Starred|etc...|
```

**Example**

```
|1|blah@clah.com|blahblah@blah.com|Hi|Hello|0|etc...|
|2|bla1@clah.com|blahbfgv@blah.com|Hi|Hello|1|etc...|
```

Hope you can match example with given table format, It's like a simple SQL database where you can query while loading inbox and check whether user has selected a mail and starred it! However you can create those star button which will change state of that table's column while being click.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Now, i want to use the starred option in my mail program, how can i use this?

Comment: When user open their mail box just iterate thru your database and show each mail on interface as per their value given in table. Just as if it is new mail show it in a different way than user's read one.

Comment: Ok fine i'll try. In my mail program i want to list out my mail in stack method (likely last mail in first place). How can i do this?

Comment: That won't be a problem as I have suggested having seq no. which will help you to track which mail is newer than the other. new mail will always be the higher number than the others, Now when you query your database you may manipulate these things and sort in an array for your list adapter.

Comment: Okay, then what can i use for starred (ratingbar or imageview or imagebutton) function?

Comment: Thats unto you my friend, Whatever suites your need! I would use image view with two small star .png files. One white coloured and another will be yellow or orange. If you like my answer make sure to accept and upvote Good luck!

Comment: I need more explanations from you. And, your answer will helpful to me. So, please give your instant message id like(gtalk or anything)

Comment: @krio let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2348/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-krio)